# Solve the system of equations for a SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, svd, singular-values

[image]

For the matrix above we're told that $A$ is a $4 \times 5$ matrix and that $\sigma_i > 0$ for all $i$. We're also told that $V^T \text{and } U$ are orthogonal matrices

We're asked to find a nonzero $X$ **(if one exists)** such that:

a)$AX = 0$ where X is a $5 \times 1$ matrix

b)$XA = 0$ where X is a $5 \times 4$ matrix

c)$AX = I_4$ where x is a $5 \times 4$ matrix

I'm confused about how to get $V^T \text{and } U$  since we don't know $A$.
Here's my attempt for part (a). I feel like if I can get one of them, then that knowledge will transfer really well to the other parts.

We know that the last column of $V^T$ is in the null space of A by definition of  the SVD. We are guaranteed to have a null space of rank $1$, since we have a $\sigma = 0$. How do I go about finding this vector in terms of $U, V, \text{and } \sigma_i$.

Is there some fact I'm missing about SVD's?

Comment: You seem to understand that the last column of $V$ will be in the null space of $A$.  In what sense is this vector not a solution to part (a)?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I'm just confused about how to go about finding the last column of $V^T$ now? Or is this all I can do with the given information? If so, then I have no idea how to go about finding parts (b) and (c). For $XA = 0 = X U \Sigma V$  but what is X?